# Menu bar icon disappear

Tags: macos, icon, menu-bar

[image: menubar]

A few days ago, when I start my OS X, I see that a few key icons are gone: including the clock, WIFI, battery and various other things.

I did the following:

1. Remove the file `~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.systemuiserver.plist`
2. run `killall SystemUIServer` in the terminal.

The icons did come back. **However after restart the icons are gone again.**

---

Other symptoms include: whenever I connect to my WIFI, and then open any application, they will get shutdown immediately, giving error messages like:

> Please run the gather_files.sh command that's attached to the radar
>   sudo gather_files.sh

These disappears after a day, but the icons are still gone. How can I get those icons back?

I am using OS X Mavericks 10.9.2

Answer (score -1):

This worked for me:

1. Reboot and hold shift key to enter safe mode
2. Launch Safari
3. Reboot normally